# Forma correcta para referirse a dos personas al mismo tiempo con diferente nivel de tratamiento

Tags: verbos, pronombres, formalidad, ustedeo

Ayer se me dio una circunstancia curiosa. Recibí en casa la visita de dos personas, a una de las cuales trato con familiaridad (de *tú*), y a la otra la trato con respeto (de *usted*). En un momento dado tuve que referirme a ambas al mismo tiempo para pedirles que tomaran asiento, y conforme mi mente iba preparando la frase me iba entrando la duda de si decir:

- "por favor, sentaos", o
- "por favor, siéntense".

Pensé que si usaba la forma de *tú* la persona a la que hablo con respeto se podría sentir ofendida, y si usaba la de *usted* la persona a la que hablo coloquialmente se iba a sentir extrañada.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de proceder en estas circunstancias? ¿Hay alguna salida intermedia?

Comment: _No hay suplemento para sentarse aqui_ would spring to mind.

Comment: @mdewey I'm not sure to understand your sentence... ^__^U

Comment: We do not charge extra for sitting down (obviously my translation was not as good as I had hoped, sigh).

Comment: @mdewey OK, I would go for "no cobramos suplemento por sentarse", or just "sentarse es gratis", but that would be a rather informal expression for someone I want to speak to with a formal tone. :-)

Comment: El español tiene una enorme riqueza para evitar sujetos personales sin que se note demasiado. Si aun así, no quieres evitar el dilema, te diría que uses el usted. Es mejor pasarse de respeto que quedarse corto.

Comment: Asiento, por favor.

Comment: Interesante es cómo jamás se me habría planteado esto como problema ya que de este lado del charco *ustedes* es la única forma de la 2a persona plural, y es de registro neutral.

Comment: A mí siempre me enseñaron usar la forma formal cuando había un grupo mixto, pero obviamente no resulta tan natural para los nativos como había pensado.

Comment: Si yo imagino esta escena como la planteaste, creo que la señora podría sentirse rara si dijeras "tú", mientras la muchacha no se sentiría mal si dijeras "usted."  A menos que hubiera una relación complicada, por ejemplo empiezas a expresar cierto interés romántico en ella, y ella de pronto sospecho que estás vacilando/dudando, por la nueva formalidad.  Pero aún así, creo que ella podría hacer an análisis de la situación, y reconocer que no está sola.

Comment: @Charlie - Nótese que puedes decir "I'm not sure I understand your sentence" or "I'm not sure how to interpret your sentence."  "Sure to understand" doesn't work in English.

Comment: Yo diría `Por favor, pueden sentarse`...

Comment: En cuanto a un intermedio pienso que , "Ambos se pueden sentar".

Answer (score 3):

Interesante pregunta. Los dialectos en los que no se usa *vosotros* evitan este dilema, usando siempre *ustedes* para el plural de *tú / vos* y *usted*.

No sé si tiene la RAE alguna prescripción para estas circunstancias, pero en el habla normal de mucha gente de España también hay cierta 'asimetría', y es normal usar *vosotros* para el plural de ambos *tú* y *usted*:

> ... *vosotros* is, in fact, the only productive second-person plural form for many Spaniards, for whom it serves as the plural of both *tú* and *usted*. Despite the universally expressed view that there exists symmetry in the Castilian system, such that *vosotros* is the plural of *tú* and *ustedes* the plural of *usted*, we show that there is in fact widespread asymmetry from singular to plural, **i.e., a person might be addressed as *usted* in the singular while at the same time forming part of a group that is addressed as *vosotros* by the same speaker.**
>
> ...
>
> Given that a particular instantiation of the second-person plural can embody multiple such individual relationships, **we first sought to determine if one V interlocutor was sufficient to trigger *ustedes* in the plural** (much as in Spanish one male member of a group renders a plural adjective grammatically masculine). **It was not.** It turns out, in fact, that **many of our interviewees admitted to using *vosotros*** (and/or its corresponding morphology) in one scenario or another **with a group of interlocutors who would *all* have been addressed individually as *usted*.**
>
> - [*Vosotros, Ustedes,* and the Myth of the Symmetrical Castilian Pronoun System](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ylguDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA263&lpg=PA263) (p263-), Terrell A. Morgan & Scott A. Schwenter